# Telerik : How to edit text from footer "Displaying items xx-yy of zz"

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

In my telerik mvc grid, how can i change the text 'Displaying items xx-yy of zz' in footer. I just want to display it as "xx-yy of zz". I tried the following methods but couldn't succeed.

```
$('#MyGrid').find('.t-status-text').text("some HTML");
```

The above code changes the text on page load, but again changes to the default text when the data loads.

I also tried editing the telerik.grid.min.js file, but finally ended up no where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easier way would be to [localize your grid](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-localization.html) and customize the  **DisplayItems** resource message.

Of course your approach could also work (with a slight improvement) - you need to execute this logic when the [OnDataBound](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#OnDataBound) event occurs (not only when the pages is loaded - as you currently do).